# Is $f : Z → Z × Z; x → (x^2 − 5, (x − 2)^2)$ injective?

Tags: functions

I have to solve the following problem: Is $f : Z → Z × Z; x → (x^2 − 5, (x − 2)^2)$ injective? Usually, I would try $f(a) = f(b) ⇔ a = b$  but the comma in the second function is confusing me. How can I facilitate the second function?

Comment: You can use your approach, the thing is the function values are tuples. For tuples to be equal, both entries need to be equal.

Comment: Does that mean I solve $x^2 - 5 = (x - 2)^2$? It's true for $x = 9/4$. Then I check if $x → 9/4$ is injective?

Comment: You need to solve two equations! They were given to you by the other answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(a)=f(b)$ implies first $a^2-5=b^2-5$, i.e. $a^2=b^2$, or $|a|=|b|.

- If $b=a$, we're done.
- If $b=-a$; we use that we also have $(a-2)^2=(b-2)^2=(a+b)^2$, which simplifies to $-4a=4a$, so $a=0$ and even if $b=-a$, we have $b=a$ also in this case.

Answer (score 0):

$f(a)=f(b)$ iff $a^2 -5 = b^2-5$ and also at the same time $(a-2)^2 = (b-2)^2$; both components of the pair should be equal.

Comment: I assumed $f(a) = x$ while $f(b) = (x^2 - 5, (x - 2)^2)$. But if $f(a)$ is the first part of the tuple and $f(b)$ the second, the relation is not-injective, right?

Comment: @tkx99 that’s completely wrong. The notation means that that $f$ value of $x$ is a pair of values, the first of which is $x^2-5$ and the second part of the pair is $(x-2)^2$.